# Dynamic update zIndex of markers in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, dynamic, z-index, map-maker

I have an OpenLayers map with 2 layers, `humanLayer` and `megafaunaLayer`. The zIndex of `humanLayer` is 15 and have marks with zIndex also 15, while the zIndex of `megafaunaLayer` is 10 and has marks of zindex 10. So `humanLayer` layer and its marks is rendered on top of `megafaunaLayer`.

Now I want to update some of the marks in `megafaunaLayer` to be on top of `humanLayer` and its marks and change the style of the marks in `megafaunaLayer` (the genus became "extinct", the precise condition is `feature.get('extinct') < year`). So I updated the Style of the marks accordingly.

The problem is that, while the marks icons are updated as desired, they do not go on top of the marks in `humanLayer`, staying below. Why is this?

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
// Human Layer
// Style
var humanstyle = new ol.style.Style({
 image: new ol.style.Icon({
  src: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="40" height="40" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="rgb(>>> 153, 204, 255)" /></svg>'
 }),
 zIndex: 15,
});
// Layer
var humanLayerSource = new ol.source.Vector();
var humanLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: humanLayerSource,
 zIndex: 15,
 style: function (feature) {
  var scale = .25 + 2*(feature.get('year')-year)/period;
  humanstyle.getImage().setScale(scale);
  return humanstyle
 }
});
// All human marks
var humanMarks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < humans.length; i++) {
 humanMarks.push(
  new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([humans[i][2],humans[i][1]])),
   year: humans[i][0]
  })
 );
}
// Add layer
map.addLayer(humanLayer);

// Megafauna Layer {{{3
// StyleS
var extinctionstyle = new ol.style.Style({
 image: new ol.style.Icon({
  src: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="12" height="12" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="6" cy="6" r="5" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="1" fill="red" /></svg>'
 }),
 zIndex: 20,
});
var alivestyle = new ol.style.Style({
 image: new ol.style.Icon({
  src: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="8" height="8" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="4" cy="4" r="3" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="1" fill="lightgreen" /></svg>'
 }),
 zIndex: 10,
});
// Layer
var megafaunaLayerSource = new ol.source.Vector();
var megafaunaLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: megafaunaLayerSource,
 zIndex: 10,
 style: function (feature) {
  return (feature.get('extinct') < year) ? alivestyle : extinctionstyle;
 }
});
// All megafauna marks
var mfMarks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < mf.length; i++) {
 mfMarks.push(
  new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([mf[i][4],mf[i][3]])),
   year: mf[i][0],
   genus: mf[i][1],
   extinct: mf[i][5],
   cause: mf[i][6]
  })
 );
}
// Add layer
map.addLayer(megafaunaLayer);
```

Comment: Layer z-index is "master" z-index, marks z-indexes are relevant only inside layer z-index. If you want to put mark from `megafaunaLayer˛` above `humanLayer`, you'll have to create new layer with z-index value of 20 and move (or clone) mark to that layer.

Comment: Or have all layers on the default zIndex use make the old layer zIndex the default for features in it.  You can also use style.setZIndex() in a style function.

Comment: @Mike Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. I tried removing the zIndex from the layers without luck. The zIndex of the marks is already included in the styles that are called in the style functions.  The other way I can think of is using for all the marks the same layer.

Comment: Yes, using a single layer would make things simpler.